# Compiling scala library with cross scala versions

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to  build git@github.com:kamon-io/Kamon.git for especially the kamon-pekko and kamon-pekko-http jars. when i run

sbt package, i get

```
[info] loading project definition from /home/dave/dev/external/Kamon/instrumentation/kamon-pekko/project
/home/dave/dev/external/Kamon/instrumentation/kamon-pekko/build.sbt:4: error: not found: value scala_2.12_version
  crossScalaVersions := Seq(`scala_2.12_version`, `scala_2.13_version`)
                            ^
/home/dave/dev/external/Kamon/instrumentation/kamon-pekko/build.sbt:4: error: not found: value scala_2.13_version
  crossScalaVersions := Seq(`scala_2.12_version`, `scala_2.13_version`)
```

can someone explain how i should build this? I'm really only interested in the 2.13 variant.

Comment: Well that sounds like the `build.sbt` file is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kamon project is a multi module project.

You need to be in the root folder to run SBT commands and then optionally choose only one of the subproject. I suspect you're running commands in the subfolder directly.

See for instance that the root `build.sbt` contains the definition of the `kamon-pekko` subproject: https://github.com/kamon-io/Kamon/blob/14cba5232cc97a8efa2e4ade5eaeeca4905280f3/build.sbt#L492

In interactive mode, for instance:

```bash
sbt
...
> projects
> project kamon-pekko
> package
```

Comment: yes you are correct. thank you, specifying the subproject inside sbt was what i didn't understand. However, it seems like that only built the  2.12 variant??

Comment: ahh i got it ++2.13